# Método Map.Keyset() não retorna todas as chaves

Tags: java

Amigos, estou com um problema e não consigo identificar a causa.

Tenho um arquivo de propriedades [aqui](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sfg2rp5xihbtu88/arquivo-sefip-mapeamento-gerador.properties?dl=0). Estou lendo ele normalmente mas quando vou pegar todas as chaves dele pelo método `Map.keySet()` nem todas as chaves estão sendo retornadas.

```
input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");

// load a properties file
prop.load(input);
for (Object string : prop.keySet()) {
   System.out.println(string.toString());
}
```

A saida não está correspondendo a todas as chaves do arquivo.

Realizei outro teste lendo todas as linhas do arquivo com `FileReader` e utilizei uma expressão regular para separar [*chave*, *valor*].

Percebi que a leitura foi realizada corretamente, e logo após, atribuí cada par de chave e valor em um `Map<String, String>` e percebi que as seguintes linhas não estão sendo atribuídas nas chaves do mapa:

```
ArquivoSefipVisao.cabecalho.dataRecolhimentoPrevidenciaSocial
ArquivoSefipVisao.$COLECAO.listaCabecalhoEmpresa.informacaoAdicional.tipoInscricaoEmpresa
ArquivoSefipVisao.$COLECAO.listaCabecalhoEmpresa.informacaoAdicional.inscricaoEmpresa
ArquivoSefipVisao.$COLECAO.listaCabecalhoEmpresa.informacaoAdicional.receitaEventoDesportivoPatrocinio
ArquivoSefipVisao.$COLECAO.listaCabecalhoEmpresa.informacaoAdicional.indicativoOrigemReceita
ArquivoSefipVisao.$COLECAO.listaCabecalhoEmpresa.informacaoAdicional.recolhimentoDeCompetenciasAnterioresInss
ArquivoSefipVisao.$COLECAO.listaCabecalhoEmpresa.informacaoAdicional.recolhimentoDeCompetenciasAnterioresOutrasEntidades
```

Comment: tentou do modo q postei abaixo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gelera, resolvi o problema implementando meu próprio leitor de properties usando expressão regular e uma lista linkada para manter a ordem. Não consegui usar o properties, estava ocorrendo o problema citado acima.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tente desta forma:

```
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;

try {

    String filename = "config.properties";
    input = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
    if (input == null) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, unable to find " + filename);
        return;
    }

    prop.load(input);

    Enumeration<?> e = prop.propertyNames();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        String key = (String) e.nextElement();
        String value = prop.getProperty(key);
        System.out.println("Key : " + key + ", Value : " + value);
    }

} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (input != null) {
        try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Não deu certo, o meu problema é o properties que de alguma forma nao armazena todas as minhas chaves no keyset. Mas resolvi o problema implementando um "PropertiesUtil lendo linha a linha do arquivo e usando expressao regular"

Comment: Posta a resposta para ajudar futuras dúvidas.